# Reduce the height of a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a rectangle which is split into 2 parts:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,orivec]{llncs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{abstract}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, fill=white!20, drop shadow,
    text centered, anchor=north, text=black, text width=3cm, scale=0.8]
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,]
    \node(domain) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, text width=7cm, text height = 0.1cm, text justified]
    {
      \begin{center}hehe\end{center}
      \nodepart{second}haha
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

There is just "hehe" in the first part, but the height is too much... `text height = 0.1cm` does not seem to work... Does anyone know how to reduce the height of the first part, let it adjusted in according to the text?

Comment: \hfil hehe \hfil

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the `text node part` to center the text.

```
\documentclass[runningheads,orivec]{llncs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{abstract}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, fill=white!20, drop shadow,
                      text centered, anchor=north, text=black, text width=3cm, scale=0.8]
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,]
    \node(domain) [abstract, rectangle split,
                   every text node part/.style={align=center},
                   rectangle split parts=2,
                   text width=7cm,
                   text height = 0.1cm,
                   text justified]
    {
      hehe
      \nodepart{second}haha
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes it's the natural way ! the trick is that the OP must avoid `\begin{center}hehe\end{center}`

Answer (score 3):

you can use \centering instead of \center

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{abstract}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, fill=white!20, drop shadow,
    text centered, anchor=north, text=black, text width=3cm, scale=0.8]
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,]
    \node(domain) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, text width=7cm, text height = 0.1cm, text justified]
    {
      \begin{center}hehe\end{center}
      \nodepart{second}haha
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,]
    \node(domain) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, text width=7cm, text height = 0.1cm, text justified]
    {
      \centering hehe\par   
      \nodepart{second}haha
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also give options to the `nodepart` independently.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}
\tikzset{abstract/.style={
    rectangle, 
    draw=black, 
    rounded corners, 
    fill=white!20, 
    drop shadow,
    text centered, 
    anchor=north, 
    text=black, 
    text width=3cm, 
    text width=7cm,
    scale=0.8
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(domain) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2 ]
{
  hehe
  \nodepart[text justified]{second} haha
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]